# Typescript type which validates abstract class and instance of class extending same abstract class

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I want to write a function in typescript with custom requirements:

- Function can be named anything let's assume it to be `speak`
- Function must accept two arguments as `a` and `b` respectively.
- Argument `a` must be an abstract class for example `speak(AbstractService)` (See example for clarification)
- Argument `b` must be a class instance which extends argument `a` abstract class . For example `RuntimeUserService`. (See example for clarification)

Here are some examples of expected behavior written in code. We will not be using any code inside `speak` function, rather just typescripts intellisense and errors are wanted.

Example:

```
// Basic Environment Setup
abstract class SampleUserService{}
class RuntimeUserService implements SampleUserService{}
class DoNotWork{}


// Example 1: Should work, because RuntimeUserService implements/extends SampleUserService provided as 1st argument.
speak(SampleUserService, new RuntimeUserService);

// Example 2: Should not work, as instance of RuntimeUserService is not created
speak(SampleUserService, RuntimeUserService);

// Example 3: Should not work as DoNotWork does not implement/extends SampleUserService provided as 1st argument.
speak(SampleUserService, new DoNotWork());

// Example 4: Do not work as it is just a class declaration similar to example 2
speak(SampleUserService, DoNotWork); // should not work
```

Here is what I have tried, but with no success.

```
type AbstractServiceConstructor<T> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;

function speak<T extends AbstractServiceConstructor<T>, U extends InstanceType<any>>(a: T, b: U) {
  // Function body
}

abstract class SampleUserService {}
class RuntimeUserService extends SampleUserService {}
class DoNotWork {}


// Gets errors for 1st argument
speak(SampleUserService, new RuntimeUserService()); // Works
speak(SampleUserService, RuntimeUserService); // Error: Argument of type 'typeof RuntimeUserService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SampleUserService'
speak(SampleUserService, new DoNotWork()); // Error: Argument of type 'DoNotWork' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SampleUserService'
speak(SampleUserService, DoNotWork); // Error: Argument of type 'typeof DoNotWork' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SampleUserService'
```

Comment: TypeScript's type system is *structural*, not *nominal*, so your three class instance types are equivalent to each other and to the empty interface.  See [The FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely). If you want to be able to distinguish them they need different structure; please add some structure to them (different members, etc) and then we can help you, perhaps like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAgd4w) shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, that works for me. Go ahead! write it as an answer so that I can accept the solution. And thanks @jcalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big problem with your example is that your classes are all *empty*, which is [known to confuse people](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  TypeScript's type system is largely [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  Two object types with the same shape (same member properties) are considered to be the same type, even if they have separate declarations. The types declared in `class Foo {}` and `abstract class Bar {}` and `interface Baz {}` and `type Qux = {}` are all identical to `{}` and thus to each other.  If you want TS to accept a `RuntimeUserService` but reject a `DoNotWork`, then you'll need to make sure that they have different structures.  The easy way to fix that is to add some structure:

```
abstract class SampleUserService { a = 1; }
class RuntimeUserService extends SampleUserService { b = 2; }
class DoNotWork { c = 3; }
```

Now those three types are different; a `SampleUserService` has a numeric `a` property; a `RuntimeUserService` has that plus a numeric `b` property, and a `DoNotWork` has a numeric `c` property but no known `a` property.

---

Once you do that you can fix `speak()` to look like this:

```
function speak<T>(a: AbstractServiceConstructor<T>, b: T) { }
```

You only need one [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` corresponding to the instance type.  Then `a` is of type `AbstractServiceConstructor<T>` (which will structurally match even non-abstract constructors; see [the release notes for `abstract` construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures), but that should be okay unless you have some unusual reason for rejecting that), and `b` is of type `T`.  Let's test it out:

```
speak(SampleUserService, new RuntimeUserService); // okay
speak(SampleUserService, RuntimeUserService); // error
speak(SampleUserService, new DoNotWork()); // error
speak(SampleUserService, DoNotWork); // error
```

It only accepts cases where the value passed as the second argument is (structurally identical to) an instance of the (possibly abstract) class constructor passed as the first argument.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCGCMGcBcCdQMbQAQIDakpZBlUBbABzQFMBVSE2HKgNwEsETkBvZUZAXmQEYBuZAF9g6TNgBKAVwB20evnKVqdRsxIAPaCWkATbHiKkKVGrAZNWycF2QAmAcNFZkAEQD2AOTfQA6m9gA1pYINgDMDiDA0ACehMwAglBwiNCm5iQAwm7SMLCSSP4APAAqAHw2ELkpyNIkAO7IABQAdK2gsADmkABc7NLRANoAugCUXOXFfMAAZjJI9NnIkHGgASWljaC9iVVIaapZOXD50EVlADRWvcVjbMIgAPQPyACi6gTEzDy9OAAWbpI0DpkHV-AFLuASAhQJJKMgpLJ5IoTCoLPJPgpZJAHhotLp9B8jEp9hZCLA3AwdCRgZheDB2J1JJjoM1gMsSKtGgZPsZlGZVJdag0EXIFLySSQRlNgE9Xu9DMxbD9-oDgdJvCCwZdafQjqBpBY3NN4TJRci+elkPRsOqUAhYBytDo2SsAlzCeaJZcRUjxajJdLZW8PchQsqAUCahrQYF2Nh3F5fGDkDo3CQbRr0aRmTjNNo9LgPX7+aTyZTqXG6Sh2h0mdoWS6OW7uUSUSWSIL6q5PN4-IFGiMpY9nsGFcgACy9dxRlAxoI6lDW5AAK1h1dQGGcVNE8Dki0g8noGFgyFOyA0Idsjc5Lc9-suCd7YKlyFlkBVkdtmsCQA)